# JSF 2 Input Field mandatory field validation required only when a value is entered

Tags: jsf-2

Currently i have a field that takes in a telephone number.

It performs a length validation without fail. What i really want is there to be length validation only when a value is input, and no validation when there is no value. How can i accomplish this?

```
<p:inputText id="corporateTel" label="#{labelResource.telephone}">
    <f:validateLength minimum="5" maximum="20" />
</p:inputText>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is already the default behaviour. Your problem is caused elsewhere. Perhaps you used an `int` instead of `Integer` or `String`, so that it defaults to `0` instead of `null`. Or perhaps you used an `Integer` while running the webapp on Tomcat/JBoss wherein the default Apache EL implementation would implicitly coerce it to `0` instead of `null`. You can turn it off by adding the following VM argument:

```
-Dorg.apache.el.COERCE_TO_ZERO=false
```

Or use `String` instead of `Integer`. This is also a more appropriate data type for phone numbers as they may have a leading `0` which would otherwise be chopped off when using `Integer`.

Comment: This is insightful. Thank you once again.

Comment: is there something that had triggered you to prompt the vm argument?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking?

Comment: Sorry what i meant was what made you think that it could also be due to Tomcat/JBoss coercing to 0 instead of null. Somehow this is happening on String too..

Comment: I just recognized the symptoms and know the possible causes based on experience.